# Ghostscript -d vs -s command line parameters

Tags: ghostscript

I recently upgraded Ghostscript from 9.10 to 9.53.3 (also tried 9.50 first).  Scripts that have run for years started failing with

```
Unrecoverable error: rangecheck in .putdeviceprops
```

After some research and trial and error testing, it seems that Ghostscript changed some of the command line switches from "-s" to "-d".  for example:

`-sGrayImageResolution=600` now errors but `-dGrayImageResolution=600` does not.

Some switches appear to accept either form.  For example:

`-sColorImageResolution=600` and `-dColorImageResolution=600` both work.

(Note:  When I say "work" I mean they do not throw the error.)

I have 2 questions

1. Where can I find a complete list of Ghostscript command line parameters?  The Ghostscript documents seem to be incomplete.
2. What is the difference between `-s` and `-d` for a switch? (this is really just a curiosity question)

Thanks

Comment: The simple fact that you indicated this change in parameters helped me to correct my syntax as well. In my case I needed to switch from -sPDFA to -dPDFA.

Answer (score -2):

The ColorImageResolution and GrayImageResolution are PostScript distiller parameters found in the VectorDevices.htm#PDFWRITE so are used with setdistillerparams and currentdistillerparams in the PostScript code for -sDEVICE=pdfwrite. Also see [TN 5151](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/distillerparameters.pdf) Acrobat Distiller Parameters. For example:

```
<< /MonoImageResolution 72 >> setdistillerparams
```

EDIT: Here are some more: [distillerparams](https://github.com/beginner3456789/explore-ghostscript/blob/master/ghostscript-distillerparams.txt)

Some settings can be defined in the system dictionary without error except are never used for anything. Be sure to check all of the documentation. There are some settings not listed in the documentation that can be found by searching in the ghostscript Resource/Init files especially for advanced users. Some of these are unique to ghostscript and beyond normal PostScript.

This is from the ghostscript Use.htm#Options :

> -Dname
> -dname
> Define a name in systemdict with value=true.
>
> -Dname=token
> -dname=token
> Define a name in systemdict with the given value. The value must be a valid PostScript token (as defined by the token operator). If the
> token is a non-literal name, it must be true, false, or null. It is
> recommeded that this is used only for simple values -- use -c (above)
> for complex values such as procedures, arrays or dictionaries.
> Note that these values are defined before other names in systemdict, so any name that conflicts with one usually in systemdict
> will be replaced by the normal definition during the interpreter
> initialization.
>
> -Sname=string
> -sname=string
> Define a name in systemdict with a given string as value. This is different from -d. For example, -dXYZ=35 on the command line is
> equivalent to the program fragment
>
> ```
> /XYZ 35 def
> ```
>
> whereas -sXYZ=35 is equivalent to
>
> ```
> /XYZ (35) def
> ```